# Included functions cant work in included header and navbar files in php

Tags: php

Am working on some website, where i have php files in includes folder and navbar, header and footer in layouts folder. When i require functions in includes folder in my index.php they work properly but when i call the same functions in header or navbar the blow with error Undefined index and the name of the function. What can i do?

Index.php:

```
<?php 
require("../includes/initialize.php");
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');    
?>

<!-- header -->
<?php 
include_layout_template('header.php'); 
include_layout_template('navbar.php'); 
?>

<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
```

navbar.php:

```
<div class="agileits_header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="w3l_offers">
        </div>
        <div class="agile-login">
            <ul>
            <?php if(!$session->is_logged_in()): ?>
                <li><a href="register.php"> Create Account </a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my initialize.php file:

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
    define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'xampp'.DS.'htdocs'.DS.'supermarket');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');

// load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'validation_functions.php');

// load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database_object.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'pagination.php');


// load database-related classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'admin.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'seed.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'comment.php');
```

?>

Comment: `include_layout_template()` is not a standard php function, should it not be `include` function?

Comment: where is `is_logged_in()` defined?

Comment: `include_layout_template()` is my function written in functions.php which is called by `require("../includes/initialize.php");` line 1 in index.php. And `is_logged_in()` is a function in sessions.php which is at second line in index.php `require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');`

Comment: maybe because you require_once the file, try just require and see what happens?

Comment: show definition include_layout_template function please

Comment: ...Also, are you asking for method AFTER the definition of class, right? Must be that way

Comment: `function include_layout_template($template="") {
 include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'layouts'.DS.$template);
}` thats  the function. @AshleyBrown i tried require and it failed. I also wondering when i use any function in index.php it work as expected but when i use it in navbar.php which is part of index.php but found in layouts it jams

Answer (score 0):

Always include all files with absolute path.
Don't use '..' for include files.

try this

```
define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

OR

```
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);
```

Comment: i did that bro, thats why i have LIB_PATH.DS but all included functions does not work in navbar but only in index.php yet navabar is included as part of index.php